# Cannot set Vertical Axis Label on Excel Chart VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to set an axis label in VBA Excel 2007.  The following all works except the axis label.

```
        Charts.Add
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range("A" & i)
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Hours"
        ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ChartName
        ActiveChart.Name = ChartName
```

I have tried it without the 'characters' element but it still does not work.  I am also wondering how to set the format to integers.

Comment: Your source consists of one cell only.

Comment: Have you tried turning on the macro recorder and adding the title? The resulting code might help.

Comment: @ja72, yes I know as this is just an extract of the whole macro and it simply gets the chart created.  I add more series of data later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I stumbled on the answer by accident.  I needed to insert the following line:

```
ActiveSheet.Select
```

before the 'HasTitle' is set and then the Axis Labels appeared and I could set the value.

Only discovered it as I typed in ActiveSheet by accident!